# PHP session login form using MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

When I enter the  username and password I get a warning like this:

> Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, array given in /home/data/www/z1760359/public_html/group/connectivity.php on line 18

And

> Incorrect password or username.

I have typed the correct credentials . 
The structure of my database is:

```
 member ID  firstName  lastName  userName  password
```

Here are my index.php and connectivity.php

index.php

```
<?php
session_start(); 
?>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#login
{

    position:absolute;
    top: 30%;
    bottom: 30%;
    left:30%;
    right:30%;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<?php


echo"<center>";
echo"<div id=\"login\">";

echo"<form method=\"POST\" action=\"connectivity.php\">";
echo"<b>Username</b>  <input type =\"text\" name=\"username\">";
echo"<br/><br/>";
echo"<b>Password</b>&nbsp;<input type =\"password\" name=\"password\">";
echo"<br/><br/>";
echo"<input type=\"submit\" value=\"submit\">";

echo"</div>";
echo"</center>";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Connectivity

```
<?php
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$host="localhost";
$uname="user";
$pword="";
$db="z1760359";
$conn=mysqli_connect($host,$uname,$pword,$db) or die("Oops something went  wrong");
session_start();

$query="Select firstName  from member where userName='$username' AND password='$password'";

if(!empty($_POST['username'])) 
{
$query_first=mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die(" Query not retrieved");
//mysqli_error($query_first);
$query_second=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_first);
$rows=mysqli_num_rows($query_second);
if($rows ==1)
{
    $_SESSION['user_name']=extract($query_second);
    echo"login successfull";
    sleep(3);
    header('Location:search.php');
}
else
{
    echo"Incorrect Password or Username";
}


}
else
{
echo"please enter the password or username";

}


?>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. In this short example you have a number of dangerous [SQL injection vulnerabilities](http://bobby-tables.com/) coming from a reckless lack of [proper escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php). Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](http://laravel.com/docs/security) built-in.

Comment: Try $query_first instead of $query_second

Comment: um... why did you un-accept my answer? is there something I'm not grasping here?

Comment: *"Try $query_first instead of $query_second"* - Huh? that's a freakin' comment. You accepted my answer then decided to switch to another; why? You're not an ethical person.

Comment: Sorry , I gave it to you . Idk how it went to some other guy

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're using the wrong variable `$query_second` in:

```
$rows=mysqli_num_rows($query_second);
```

which should be `$query_first` for your query and not for `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`.

```
$rows=mysqli_num_rows($query_first);
```

---

Sidenotes:

Your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Use [**`mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).

I noticed you may be storing passwords in plain text. If this is the case, it is highly discouraged.

For password storage, use [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471) or PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function. For PHP < 5.5 use the [`password_hash() compatibility pack`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

*As a matter of fact,* [ircmaxell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/338665/ircmaxell) put up an answer earlier in regards to using PDO (prepared statements) with `password_hash()`.

- Have a look https://stackoverflow.com/a/29778421/

---

**Edit:**

> *"How can i store firstName from the database to $_SESSION['user_name'] ?"*

```
$username = $_POST['username']; 

$_SESSION['user_name'] = $_POST['username'];
$saved_session = $_SESSION['user_name'];
echo $saved_session;
```

Comment: Alternatively you can `count($query_second)`.

Comment: How can i store firstName from the database to   $_SESSION['user_name'] ?

Comment: @AdarshJayakumar try `$username = $_POST['username']; 
$_SESSION['user_name'] = $username;`

Comment: I want to retrieve  firstName from the SQL query to be stored in session   and not username from the form

Comment: @AdarshJayakumar reload my answer and look under **Edit:** near the bottom.

Comment: @fred When i hst the file and run it  i get some thing like this  -------->                           login successfull , Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/data/www/z1760359/public_html/group/connectivity.php:24) in /home/data/www/z1760359/public_html/group/connectivity.php on line 27

Comment: @AdarshJayakumar that's because you have output before your PHP. Please read the following on Stack http://stackoverflow.com/q/8028957/ - but you need to post a new question, as this one has already been answered and have helped you out more than many would.

Answer (score 0):

Try $query_first instead of $query_second