# How to decode the password: $password = md5( addslashes( $_POST['password'] ) );

Tags: php, cryptography, passwords, md5

As the title, please kindly show me how to decode a password string encoded by this:

> $password = md5( addslashes( $_POST['password'] ) );

For the example: f21601fea7f496cfbc23f7310e13f941

Thank you!

Comment: It can be reversed, but not so easly...

Comment: @KrzysztofTrzos More than one password can generate the same MD5 hash, so it *technically* can't be reversed - there are an infinite number of strings that'll match any one MD5 hash.

Comment: *"How to decode the password:"* - **don't** - call it a blessing in disguise that's it's not working. Here, ircmaxell posted an answer earlier using a much safer hashing method http://stackoverflow.com/a/29778421/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MD5 is a one-way [hashing algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function). The nature of such an algorithm is **it cannot be reversed**. It it could, it'd be an encryption algorithm, not hashing.

Before you go switch to an encryption algorithm, **don't**. Passwords should always be stored as hashes if possible (there are unusual cases, like where you're storing a password for a third-party system). This protects your users if your code/database get compromised.

For simple strings, it may be possible to lookup an MD5 hash in a "rainbow table". As an example, `098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6` can be put into a tool like http://md5cracker.org/ to find out the password is *probably* `test` (but it could be another string that results in the same hash, known as [a collision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#Collision_vulnerabilities)).

**Note:** MD5 is also [insecure](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure) because of the speed for which you can generate a rainbow table. You should use PHP's built in `password_hash` / `password_verify` functions when hashing passwords, as they take advantage of the secure `bcrypt` hashing algorithm.

Comment: Actually I also add a field (in sign up form) that would store user's password in plain text, but when i search that text in DB, it didnt work.
`$password = md5( addslashes( $_POST['password'] ) );
    $pwd = addslashes( $_POST['pwd'] ) ;`

Comment: @ChristopherMcKenny Don't do that. Also, stop with the `addslashes` stuff. It's unnecessary in your code (MD5 hashes will never have a `"` character) and it's not sufficient to protect against SQL injection either.

Comment: You also need to [salt](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm#salt) your passwords before hashing. `password_hash` and `password_verify` take care of all of this for you.