# Destroy session with redirect

Tags: php, session, logout

When I click on Logout link it redirects to an empty page.

Here is the `Login.php` file:

```
<?php

    session_start();
    $_SESSION['logout']= 'username';

    include_once('config.php');

    if(isset($_POST['btn'])) {
        $username = addslashes($_POST['username']);
        $password = addslashes(md5($_POST['password']));

        $query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM register WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password' ")
        or die(mysql_error());
        $result = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

        if($result['username']==$username) {
            echo "You have successfully loged in <br>";
            $check = true;
        }else {
            echo "Wrong Login or Password <br>";
        }
    }

?>

<a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
```

`Logout.php` file:

```
<?php

    session_start();
    if(isset($_POST['logout'])) {
        session_destroy();
        header("Location:login.html");
        }
?>
```

Please can you correct my code and tell me what I've done wrong?

Comment: What is your code going to do if `$_POST['logout']` _isn't_ set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line in your logout

```
if(isset($_POST['logout'])) {
```

should be using `$_SESSION` and not `$_POST`

as per

```
$_SESSION['logout']= 'username';
```

You're also mixing MySQL APIs with `or die(mysql_error())` which should read as `or die(mysqli_error($connect))`

I noticed you are storing passwords using MD5; it's old and considered broken.

I recommend you use [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471) or PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function. For PHP < 5.5 use the [`password_hash() compatibility pack`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Plus, in regards to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/) which you are open to,  [**use `mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*.

---

See ircmaxell's solution to using `password_hash()` and PDO with prepared statements:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/29778421/

---

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

Comment: Thank you so much helped me more than i needed

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your logout.php file, you are listening for a $_POST.

```
if(isset($_POST['logout'])) { ...
```

However, you are just using a href to link to the log out page

```
<a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
```

This means there is never going to be a $_POST['logout'] because it isn't a form (but an actual link).

Therefore as it is a link, you can just remove the if(isset($_POST['logout'])) { .. and do something like this:

```
<?php

session_start();
session_destroy();
header("Location:login.html");

?>
```