# my php post 2 id insted of one

Tags: php, sql

wen i register a account EX: my , game 
in my sql EX:
id name password 1  my  game 2  my  game
but i only press submit once and it ads it twice my php its down below and my my html its a form lablel imput submit

```
<?php

define('DB_NAME', 'abcd');
define('DB_USER', 'abcd');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '******');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

 if (!$link)
{
die('Could NOT Connect: rong pass ' . mysql_error(rong_pass));
}
$db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

if (!$db_selected) 
{
die ('Cant\'t use' . DB_NAME. 'abcd' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'log in succes';
$id = $_POST["id"];
$com_name = $_POST["com_name"]; // Since method=”post” in the form
$log_in = $_POST["log_in"];
$password = $_POST["password"];



$sql = "INSERT INTO members (com_name, log_in, password) VALUES                   
('$_POST[com_name]','$_POST[log_in]','$_POST[password]')";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die (" could not save record sorry ");

mysql_close();
?>
</ p><a href="demo.html">inapoi</a>

//tot odata ai fost adaugat in baza noastra de date
```

Comment: we will need to see your form page with the elements in it that posts to your script that you've posted in your question

Comment: Well, you do execute the query twice: `$result = mysql_query($sql);

$result = mysql_query($sql)`. And you have an sql injection problem. Two :-)

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), you are using obsolete/deprecated mysql libraries, and if you're getting two inserts into the DB, then this code is being executed twice: because you ARE calling mysql_query() twice.

Comment: right i found it and fix it for now  i work on posting log in check to be able to see the site and when i get all this to work together i will have to come back and see how can stop injections or other attacks thx a loot for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO members (com_name, log_in, password) VALUES                   
('$_POST[com_name]','$_POST[log_in]','$_POST[password]')";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die (" could not save record sorry ");
```

You're running the SQL Insert twice. Remove one of those and all will be good! :)

Answer (score 2):

The reason being is, you're calling `mysql_query()` **twice**.

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die (" could not save record sorry ");
```

- **Remove one.**

---

**Important** sidenote:

Your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Use [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*.

---

Plus, this `or die (" could not save record sorry ")` doesn't help you.

Use `or die(mysql_error())` to get the real error once that fires up.

---

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors, should there be any along the line.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

---

**Regarding password storage:**

I noticed you may be storing passwords in plain text. If this is the case, it is highly discouraged.

I recommend you use [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471) or PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function. For PHP < 5.5 use the [`password_hash() compatibility pack`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

---

**Edit:** It seems that Q&A has been deleted, *no idea why*.

<strike>- Consult ircmaxell's answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/29778421/ where he utilizes PDO with prepared statements and `password_hash()`.</strike>

**Pulled from his answer:**

Just use a library. Seriously. They exist for a reason.

- PHP 5.5+: use [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
- PHP 5.3.7+: use [`password-compat`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) (a compatibility pack for above
- All others: use [phpass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/)

Don't do it yourself. If you're creating your own salt, **YOU'RE DOING IT WRONG**. You should be using a library that handles that for you.

```
$dbh = new PDO(...);

$username = $_POST["username"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("insert into users set username=?, email=?, password=?");
$stmt->execute([$username, $email, $hash]);
```

And on login:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$result = $stmt->execute([$_POST['username']]);
$users = $result->fetchAll();
if (isset($users[0]) {
    if (password_verify($_POST['password'], $users[0]->password) {
        // valid login
    } else {
        // invalid password
    }
} else {
    // invalid username
}
```

Comment: Looks like you'll be busy for a while, I'm going to get some coffee. Oh, and the whole plain-text password stuff probably needs to copy-pasted in as well ;-)

Comment: @jeroen oh yeah.... that's next. Enjoy the coffee!

Comment: @jeroen done. I never take mine "plain" neither, but as an added "specialty". Plus, a cappuccino is so much tastier.

Comment: *Sidenote about my link in the answer:* I honestly don't know why that Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/q/29777684/ was deleted. I thought it made for a good reference. Only 10k+ members can view it, sorry.

Comment: @jeroen ah, will you lookah dat! thanks for the update. thought I'd pull the code from his answer though, just in case it disappears again.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are running the query twice....

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die (" could not save record sorry ");
```