# I have the same error message when i put any error in the file

Tags: php, mysql

when I submit this form i have the same error message all the time . even if i put right or wrong password or don't put password or i write the name of the data base wrong . all of this wrongs i have the same error message : 
Please enter a username and password . 
so what is the problem . and i am sure about my fields on data base .

```
    <?

    session_start();
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];


    if ($username && $password)
    {

        $connect = mysql_connect("localhsost","root","adminffpass") or die("Couldent connet to database ");
        mysql_select_db("login") or die("No data base found ");

        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'");

        $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

        if ($numrows !=0)
        {

            while ($row= mysql_fetch_array($query)) 
            {

                $dbusername = $row['username'];
                $dbpassword = $row['password'];

            }

            if ($username == $dbusername && $password==$dbpassword)
            {
                echo "Login successul .<a href='memeberarea.php'>Click to enter member area</a>";
                $_SESSION['username'] = $dbusername;
            }
            else
                echo "incorrect  password  ";

        }
        else
           die ("That user name dosent exist");

   }
   else
     die ("Please enter a username and password");


    ?>
```

Comment: _"the same error message"_ which one?

Comment: Please format your code properly. It's quite difficult to understand the question as it's currently presented.

Comment: Your POST arrays are most likely failing. Getting an Undefined index xxx I'll bet. Plus, if your short tags aren't enabled, change `<?` to `<?php`. Not storing a hash for a password. tsk tsk. This code is totally unsafe to use.

Comment: Note: Your code is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/4193263). To fix this critical security hole, use Prepared Statements.

Comment: by formatting your code, you would see that your `Please enter a username and password` is in the `else` of `if ($username && $password)`. So you need to find out why that is failing. Are your `$_POST` names correct? Does your form have inputs with name attributes the same as those `$POST`?

Comment: `localhsost` <= yo............ typo!

Comment: if i write wrong name database i don't have any error . why ?

Comment: because you never enter into the code of the `if ($username && $password)` where the database connection is. You first need to fix that issue, and then you would have had an issue connecting to your database as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Even if i put right or wrong password or don't put password or i write the name of the data base wrong . all of this wrongs i have the same error message*

Typo: `localhsost` for one thing. Plus, you may not be able to use `mysql_` functions, since they are deprecated and may not be available for you to use.

Plus, your POST arrays may be failing, so make sure your form is a POST method and that your elements bear the name attribute.

I.e.:

```
<input type="text" name="username">
```

etc.

> *if i write wrong name database i don't have any error . why ?"*

Because, you're just using `or die("Couldent connet to database ")` instead of getting the *real* error `mysql_error()`

`mysql_connect()` => http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

Your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Use [**`mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).

I noticed you may be storing passwords in plain text. If this is the case, it is highly discouraged.

For password storage, use [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471) or PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function. For PHP < 5.5 use the [`password_hash() compatibility pack`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

---

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

---

Plus, instead of `if ($username && $password)` you should be using a conditional `!empty()` for your inputs.

---

It is also best to use proper and consistent bracing throughout your code.

```
else{
    echo "incorrect  password  ";
}
```

etc.

- Not doing so, could have adverse effects.

---

**Storing a password hash**

Using PDO with prepared statements and `password_hash()`:

- Pulled from ircmaxell's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29778421/

Just use a library. Seriously. They exist for a reason.

- PHP 5.5+: use [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
- PHP 5.3.7+: use [`password-compat`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) (a compatibility pack for above
- All others: use [phpass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/)

Don't do it yourself. If you're creating your own salt, **YOU'RE DOING IT WRONG**. You should be using a library that handles that for you.

```
$dbh = new PDO(...);

$username = $_POST["username"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("insert into users set username=?, email=?, password=?");
$stmt->execute([$username, $email, $hash]);
```

And on login:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$result = $stmt->execute([$_POST['username']]);
$users = $result->fetchAll();
if (isset($users[0]) {
    if (password_verify($_POST['password'], $users[0]->password) {
        // valid login
    } else {
        // invalid password
    }
} else {
    // invalid username
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may print some information for yourself, so you could see, what's wrong. Change the following line:

```
echo "incorrect  password  ";
```

to something like this:

```
echo "incorrect  password, u:[$username/$dbusername] p:[$password/$dbpassword]";
```

If you will see that detailed message, you will know, what's wrong.

EDIT: of course, don't left pwd printing in your final code :)

Comment: This is more a comment rather than a valid answer.