# Why wont this check to see if a user exists?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm performing a query to check if a user exists before adding it to the database. If that result comes back then die and echo 'username already exists' but if it comes back empty then add the new user to the database.

For some reason it just adds a new user to the database anyway.

```
        //If post was 
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        // Check if username is blank
        if (!isset($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['username'])) {
            echo "Username was blank<br />";
            die();
        } else {
            $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['username']);
        }

        // Check if password is blank
        if (!isset($_POST['password']) || empty($_POST['password'])) {
            echo "Password was blank<br />";
            die();
        } else {
            $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['password']);
            $password2 = md5($password);
            //echo $password;
        }

        // Check if email is blank
        if (!isset($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['email'])) {
            echo "Email was blank<br />";
            die();
        } else {
            $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['email']);
            //$password = md5($password);
            //echo $password;
        }

        //Check to see if username alread exsists 
        $query_check = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user = '$username' LIMIT 1";
        $result_check = mysqli_query($connection, $query_check);

         if(count(mysqli_fetch_array($result_check)) === 1) {
            echo "Username exists.";
            die();   

         } else {
                $query = "INSERT INTO users (user, pass, email) VALUES ('$username','$password2','$email');";
                $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
                if($result){  // returned TRUE, e.g. in case of a DELETE sql  
                    $_SESSION["username"] = $username;
                    header("Location: ../profile.php");

                } else { // returned FALSE
                    //echo "Error: " . mysqli_error($connection);
                    echo "Error during register <a href='../register.php'>Back To Register</a>";
                    die();
                }
         }



    } else {
        header("Location: ../index.php");
}
```

Comment: firstly, this doesn't help you `mysql_error()` use `mysqli_error($connection)`

Comment: And please tell me `$username` is not simply gotten from something like `$_POST['username']`

Comment: there is no such function in php `mysqli_fetch_array`

Comment: @Alex [Oh really?](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)

Comment: @Machavity my bad :-) I always use statement functions :-)

Comment: `if(mysqli_num_rows($result_check) >0)` and make sure `$username` is defined. We don't know how/where if it is even defined.

Comment: why not just  `>0` ?

Comment: @Alex sorry that's what I meant. arf~ we all make mistakes eh? wink

Comment: @Machavity regarding the username no  it goes through an escape string.

Comment: @Alex I think you're looking for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/. Please be sure to stop by the help center there.

Comment: @Alex Note that this particular question is off-topic for Code Review. It is seeking debugging help.

Comment: I will adjust my code to show full

Comment: @M0n5terBunny in your original question you were not using count. It is not generally acceptable to edit your question with the content of the answers for it. Was that the solution? Is your user still inserted even though you added count?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After taking a few minutes testing your code, found that you're using the wrong function.

[`mysqli_fetch_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php):

> *Fetch a result row as an associative, a numeric array, or both*

You're trying to fetch an associative array.

As opposed to [`mysqli_num_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php):

> *Gets the number of rows in a result*

Replace (and which seems to have been taken from  Félix's answer)

```
if(count(mysqli_fetch_array($result_check)) === 1)
```

with

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result_check) == 1)
```

or

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result_check) > 0)
```

Your original post contained:

```
if(mysqli_fetch_array($result_check) === 1)
```

which still stands to be the wrong method.

---

- I even said to use [`mysqli_num_rows()`](http://php.net/mysqli_num_rows) [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30245973/why-wont-this-check-to-see-if-a-user-exists#comment48593014_30245973), but nothing was said about it:

> *`if(mysqli_num_rows($result_check) >0)` and make sure `$username` is defined. We don't know how/where if it is even defined*.

---

Now, if THAT fails, then your form element isn't named, and/or something else in your form is failing you.

I.e.: `<input type="text" name="username">`

---

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

---

**Regarding using MD5.**

That isn't considered safe to use anymore, as far as password hashing goes.

- That technology is old and is considered broken.

For password storage, use [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471) or PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function.

For PHP < 5.5 use the [`password_hash() compatibility pack`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

---

Pulled from [ircmaxell's  answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29778421/) which uses PDO with prepared statements and `password_hash()`:

Just use a library. Seriously. They exist for a reason.

- PHP 5.5+: use [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
- PHP 5.3.7+: use [`password-compat`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) (a compatibility pack for above
- All others: use [phpass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/)

Don't do it yourself. If you're creating your own salt, **YOU'RE DOING IT WRONG**. You should be using a library that handles that for you.

```
$dbh = new PDO(...);

$username = $_POST["username"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("insert into users set username=?, email=?, password=?");
$stmt->execute([$username, $email, $hash]);
```

And on login:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$result = $stmt->execute([$_POST['username']]);
$users = $result->fetchAll();
if (isset($users[0]) {
    if (password_verify($_POST['password'], $users[0]->password) {
        // valid login
    } else {
        // invalid password
    }
} else {
    // invalid username
}
```

---

**Footnotes:**

I noticed you are using headers.

You should add `exit;` after each header. Otherwise, your code may want to continue executing.

```
header("Location: ../profile.php");
    exit;
```

and do the same for the other one also.

You're also using sessions. `session_start();` isn't present in your posted and will fail if it isn't included; *an insight*.

Comment: @Darren I like to add a bit of *zing to the punch* ;-) and thanks.

Comment: It is a well worded, well deserving answer sir :-)

Answer (score 1):

here

```
 if(mysqli_fetch_array($result_check) === 1) {
```

the value returned by [mysqli_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) won't be an integer but an array. You seem to want to count it:

```
 if(count(mysqli_fetch_array($result_check)) === 1) {
```

In the case somehow two users would have been inserted for whatever reason, checking if count is greater than 0 may prevent a third one being inserted:

```
 if(count(mysqli_fetch_array($result_check)) > 0) {
```

Comment: Looks like OP may have borrowed your code in their edit `if(count(mysqli_fetch_array($result_check)) === 1)`

Comment: It does seem so... Not sure how to react.

Comment: my guess is, their HTML form. could be an unnamed element, could be no post method; who knows. My vote to close as unclear, hasn't been retracted. the question is getting too chatty.

Comment: I think the OP's ran off. I'm not sticking around. They'll need to debug their code. *au revoir*.

Comment: OP was using the wrong function after all and probably either didn't see [my comment to them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30245973/why-wont-this-check-to-see-if-a-user-exists/30250063#comment48593014_30245973) and mentioned it in an answer I posted. I won't retract my upvote for your answer, and for a few reasons ;-)

Comment: merci pour la leçon :) @Fred-ii-

Comment: ça m'a fait plaisir Félix :-)