# Using of md5 function

Tags: php, hash, md5, password-hash

On php. How we use md5 encryption method? Suppose a login form. When we want an encrypted text we use

```
$encryptedtxt=md5('text');
```

Then we sent this $encryptedtxt to database. Now if we want this $encryptedtxt to compare with user new inputs to login , what should we do? If we should return text from encrypted form of it, how? Tnx.

Comment: *"what should we do?"* - If this is for passwords, the answer is simple; **don't use it**. It's 30 years old and not safe to use anymore. Plus, "how-to's" can be found on the Web. Show us what you tried.

Comment: Tnx! @Fred-ii- is there any other way to secure the password more than normal?

Comment: For password storage, use [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471) or PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function. For PHP < 5.5 use the [`password_hash() compatibility pack`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: @Fred-ii- one another question , why this is not a deprecated function, when you say that is not so safe? if there is better way , why this is still use by people? tnx for your attention.

Comment: I posted an answer for you below, which uses safe methods, in both passwords and MySQL. There are a few links you can read up on why MD5 isn't safe anymore.

Comment: @Sonoo - It isn't deprecated because md5 has perfectly valid uses still, it's just not good for password hashing

Comment: @MarkBaker I agree with you on that aspect Mark. ^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MD5 is no longer considered safe to use for password hashing, it's 30 years old and is considered "broken".

Use a modern-day method, including prepared statements.

Here are a few articles you can read up on:

- https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/37454/why-are-md5-collisions-dangerous
- https://www.bentasker.co.uk/blog/security/201-why-you-should-be-asking-how-your-passwords-are-stored

---

Pulled from ircmaxell's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/29778421/

Just use a library. Seriously. They exist for a reason.

- PHP 5.5+: use [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
- PHP 5.3.7+: use [`password-compat`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) (a compatibility pack for above
- All others: use [phpass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/)

Don't do it yourself. If you're creating your own salt, **YOU'RE DOING IT WRONG**. You should be using a library that handles that for you.

```
$dbh = new PDO(...);

$username = $_POST["username"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("insert into users set username=?, email=?, password=?");
$stmt->execute([$username, $email, $hash]);
```

And on login:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$result = $stmt->execute([$_POST['username']]);
$users = $result->fetchAll();
if (isset($users[0]) {
    if (password_verify($_POST['password'], $users[0]->password) {
        // valid login
    } else {
        // invalid password
    }
} else {
    // invalid username
}
```

Comment: or you could just make as dupe :-)

Comment: @Dagon sure, but given the other answer below, I had to give them a "safe" method. OP can do what they want with it; closed question or not. ;-)

Comment: oh we know you just want the easy rep points :-)

Comment: @Dagon points are nice, sure but this isn't about points, it's about giving the OP "the right time of day" ;-)

Comment: So one more point from me, you cannot repeat this too much :-)

Comment: @martinstoeckli Thank you Martin. I know; even with the so many duplicates on Stack, why is it do they not find it? It's a mystery to me. The Web I guess.... is just far too vast and saturated; *baffled*. - *Cheers*