# Form information is not updating to my Database

Tags: php, sql, html, mysqli, xampp

I have been stuck on this for 3 days now and any help would be very much appreciated. 
Please note that i have the php and html in one page for now until i get it working then once it has been fixed i will place the php connection script into its usual folder.
when I get onto the sign up page i can see that i am connected to my and i can fill out my form and submit it without any errors, however the database will not be updated and when i refresh the database no new users are found.
Below is my code so far if anyone could show me what i am doing wrong or where i could improve to fix this error i would be trully thankfull. 
Thank you in advance!

```
<?php
    $host="localhost";
    $dbuser="root";
    $pass="********";
    $dbname="amsadler";
    $con = mysqli_connect ($host, $dbuser, $pass, $dbname);
    if (mysqli_connect_errno ())
    {
        die ("Connection Failed!" . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    else
    {
    echo "Connected to database {$dbname} ";
    }

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $fname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST ['fname']);
        $lname= mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST ['lname']);
        $email= mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST ['email']);
        $pswrd= mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST ['pswrd']);

        $sql = $con->query("INSERT INTO users ( fname, lname, email, pswrd,)
                    VALUES ( ' {$fname} ' , ' {$lname} ' , ' {$email} ' , ' {$pswrd} ' )");

    }
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <title>Signup</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="description of webpage">
    <meta name="keywords" content="keywords go here">
    <meta name="author" content="amsadler">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/signup.css">
    <link rel="index" href="index.php">
    <link rel="icon" href="img/favicon.png" sizes="16x16" type="image/png">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="header">
        <div id="logo">
                <a href="index.php"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo" title="blah blah"/></a>
        </div>
    </div>

     <div id="signupform">
        <form method="post"><br>
            <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="First name">
            <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" placeholder="Last name"><br><br>
            <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email address">
            <input type="password" id="pswrd" name="pswrd" placeholder="Password"><br><br>
            <input id="button" type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </div>

<?php
    include ("inc/footer.php");
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems here.

One of them being with your conditional statement:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){...}
```

Nothing in there will fire up because of a missing name attribute "submit".

Name your submit button:

```
<input name="submit" id="button" type="submit" value="Submit">
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Then a trailing comma in your query:

```
( fname, lname, email, pswrd,)
                            ↑
```

remove it

```
( fname, lname, email, pswrd)
```

Add `or die(mysqli_error($con))` to `mysqli_query()`

Using error checking on the query will have shown another syntax error soon as you would name the submit button:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

No errors you say? You're most likely not checking for them or your system isn't setup for it and to display them.

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Displaying errors should only be done in staging, and never production.

- It would have signaled an undefined index submit notice.

In order to make absolutely sure that it was a successful query, use `affected_rows()`.

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php

---

I noticed you may be storing passwords in plain text. If this is the case, it is highly discouraged.

I recommend you use [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471) or PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function. For PHP < 5.5 use the [`password_hash() compatibility pack`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Make sure that if and when you do use a safe hashing method, that your password column is long enough to hold the hash.

A safe bet is VARCHAR(255) which PHP.net recommends on using. Details are listed on their website.

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Comment: Man thank you so much I am new at this and i am using notepadd++ i did not see see the ( fname, lname, email, pswrd,) and i named submit
                                                                       ↑
It is working now I am learning on youtube how to do this and when i get stuck i come here for proffesional advice if i cannot fix it!

thanks again man may you have an awesome day.

Comment: @AnthonySadler  You're most welcome Anthony and was glad to have been of help, *cheers* and you have a great day too, thanks.

Comment: thanks on the crypt blowfish aswell I have not got that far yet i am currently watching this series on youtube. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=InmQaOENDhA

and learning as i go

Comment: @AnthonySadler You're welcome. You may want to have a look at one of ircmaxell's answer here on Stack http://stackoverflow.com/a/29778421/ it uses PDO with prepared statements and both versions of password_hash(). The PDO method can easily be converted to mysqli_ with prepared statements.