# PHP, SQL, User Database

Tags: php, sql

I hope I formatted the code properly. I am having trouble making this if statement to work. I've searched and from what it looks like this statement should work. However, when I run it no matter the password if the username starts with kacey then it goes to `echo "Logged in as: " . kacey;`
Likewise, if I put the input to kaceyfeewaf, it still goes to `echo "Logged in as: " . $myuser;` This happens regardless of the password I put in. the line `$result['username']` should validate to KACEY.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $dbTable WHERE username = $myuser AND password = $mypass";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

if($result['username'] = $myuser && $result['password'] = $mypass;) 
{
    echo "Logged in as: " . $myuser;    
} else {
    echo "Fail "; 
  }
```

Comment: You are using assignment operator in place of comparison operator in the if statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few issues here.

Firstly, the variables you have in your query are strings, therefore they require to be quoted:

```
WHERE username = '$myuser' AND password = '$mypass'
```

Having `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()` would have signaled the syntax error.

Then you're assigning instead of comparing with

```
if($result['username'] = $myuser && $result['password'] = $mypass;)
```

use two equals `==`

However, that isn't how you check if those rows exist.

You need to use `mysql_num_rows()` or use a `while` loop while using a function to fetch/iterate over results found.

Here is an MySQLi example using `mysqli_num_rows()`:

```
$conn=mysqli_connect("hostname","username","password","db");

$check_select = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `users` 
                                     WHERE email = '$email' AND pw='$pass'"); 

$numrows=mysqli_num_rows($check_select);

if($numrows > 0){
// do something
}
```

Now, we don't know where those variables have been assigned, and if from a form that it's using a POST method with matching name attributes.

I.e.:

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="username">
...
</form>

$username = $_POST['username'];
```

Another thing which is unknown to us is the MySQL API you're using to connect with. Make sure that you are indeed using the same one as you are using to query with, being `mysql_`. Different APIs do not intermix, such as `mysqli_` or PDO. Use the same one from connection to querying.

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Displaying errors should only be done in staging, and never production.

---

I noticed you may be storing passwords in plain text. If this is the case, it is highly discouraged.

I recommend you use [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471) or PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function. For PHP < 5.5 use the [`password_hash() compatibility pack`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Here is a PDO solution pulled from one of ircmaxell's answers:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/29778421/

Just use a library. Seriously. They exist for a reason.

- PHP 5.5+: use [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
- PHP 5.3.7+: use [`password-compat`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) (a compatibility pack for above)
- All others: use [phpass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/)

Don't do it yourself. If you're creating your own salt, **YOU'RE DOING IT WRONG**. You should be using a library that handles that for you.

```
$dbh = new PDO(...);

$username = $_POST["username"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("insert into users set username=?, email=?, password=?");
$stmt->execute([$username, $email, $hash]);
```

And on login:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$result = $stmt->execute([$_POST['username']]);
$users = $result->fetchAll();
if (isset($users[0]) {
    if (password_verify($_POST['password'], $users[0]->password) {
        // valid login
    } else {
        // invalid password
    }
} else {
    // invalid username
}
```

Comment: This looks a lot cleaner then what I was doing to check. I am having a difficult time getting the if($numrows > 0) { } to work, I'm trying to research it to understand it better. Thanks!

Comment: @Fred-ii- Growing cactus again? *Ralph* :]

Comment: I sure am RR @Rizier123 lovin' every minute of it.

Comment: The note about quotibg should come with a warning not to use because it is susceptible to SQL injection. The answer is correct about not doing it oneself, but a more explicit warning should still be there.

Answer (score 1):

You should use == instead of simple = for your if condition

Answer (score 1):

First of all delete that if stmt and make new one where you check for num rows. If there is num rows > 0 you have valid login. And then print needed results from database od current query.

Edit:

You have = insted of == or === so stmt is always true.