# Getting an error using mysqli_escape_string function

Tags: php, mysql, escaping

I get an error on the last line on `mysqli_escape_string($hash));` by using the following code:

```
$hash = md5( rand(0,1000) );
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, password, hash) VALUES (?, ?, mysqli_escape_string($hash))");
$password = md5($password);
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $username, $password, mysqli_escape_string($hash));
```

It says, that the `mysqli_escape_string($hash))` is a non-object. 
But using only `$hash` instead doesn't help either

Can someone help?

Comment: RTM >>> http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php `string mysqli_real_escape_string ( mysqli $link , string $escapestr )`

Comment: You really shouldn't use MD5 password hashes. Please use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: Parameterize the hash. `?, mysqli_escape_string($hash)` should be `?, ?`. Also don't need to escape when parameterizing.

Comment: It is recommended that you do your own research before posting your question on SO. See https://stackoverflow.com/tour for more information.

Comment: that too @chris85 that answer below has their work cut out for them.

Comment: there is far too many things wrong with this code and will be extremely difficult to provide a solution. You're best finding yourself a piece of working code, and there are many out there.

Comment: do yourself a favor and use this, one of ircmaxell's answers http://stackoverflow.com/a/29778421/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are far too many things wrong with your code and will be extremely difficult to provide a solution by fixing what you have now.

Firstly, MD5 is no longer considered safe to use for password storage.

Consult:

- https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5

Plus, you're not using prepared statements correctly.

- Consult: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

As I stated, the `mysqli_escape_string()` function requires a database connection be passed as the first parameter:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

**Do yourself a favor** and use this, one of ircmaxell's answers https://stackoverflow.com/a/29778421/

Pulled from his answer:

Just use a library. Seriously. They exist for a reason.

- PHP 5.5+: use [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
- PHP 5.3.7+: use [`password-compat`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) (a compatibility pack for above)
- All others: use [phpass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/)

Don't do it yourself. If you're creating your own salt, **YOU'RE DOING IT WRONG**. You should be using a library that handles that for you.

```
$dbh = new PDO(...);

$username = $_POST["username"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("insert into users set username=?, email=?, password=?");
$stmt->execute([$username, $email, $hash]);
```

And on login:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$result = $stmt->execute([$_POST['username']]);
$users = $result->fetchAll();
if (isset($users[0]) {
    if (password_verify($_POST['password'], $users[0]->password) {
        // valid login
    } else {
        // invalid password
    }
} else {
    // invalid username
}
```

Comment: Thank you, really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Your code should be

```
$hash = md5( rand(0,1000) );
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, password, hash) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$password = md5($password);
$stmt->bind_param('sss', $username, $password, $hash);
```

You don't need to escape with parameterized queries.

Issues you had, your `escape` function was incorrect you need the object with the function when using OO approach.

```
$mysqli->real_escape_string($hash);
```

would have been what you wanted.

You also were binding that value again though which would have thrown an error and didn't set it in the variable types being passed.

> A string that contains one or more characters which specify the types for the corresponding bind variables.

So

```
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $username, $password, mysqli_escape_string($hash));
```

should have had three 's's because there are three strings, and no need for the escaping.

Also `md5`ing passwords isn't the best practice anymore, take a look at:

[Secure hash and salt for PHP passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401656/secure-hash-and-salt-for-php-passwords)

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure

Comment: You *really* don't want to encourage someone to use MD5 for password hashes, do you? http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure The OP should really use PHP's built-in password functions.

Comment: @chris85 Thanks a lot, really appreciated. :)

And jay, I will follow your advice also, thanks. :)

Comment: @JayBlanchard not encouraging, added notes about it as well. I prefer md5ing than plain text though, so OP has a better starting approach than a number of questions I see.

Comment: OP got their solution and that's what's important ;-) Btw, I didn't use the links or anything else in your answer to formulate mine Chris ;-) cheers

Comment: Oh... I just noticed the OP chose my answer and unaccepted yours. No idea why they did that Chris. Wasn't my goal to get one.

Comment: @Fred-ii- no objections from me, your answer goes more into depth and provides OP the better hashing method.

Comment: @chris85 Yours is just as informative Chris and does provide enough for them to dig deeper into researching. *Show a person how to fish...*, you know the rest, am sure ;-) *cheers*