# How do I check the password?

Tags: php, forms, authentication, passwords

recently revealed a problem in my login handler. The thing is, that even though the entered password is correct and matches the one in the database, script still sends me to the mistake page.

```
session_start();
include ("db.php");

 if (isset($_POST['login'])) {                                     
        $login = $_POST['login']; 
        $login = stripslashes($login);
        $login = htmlspecialchars($login);
        $login = trim($login);
        if ($login == '') {
            unset($login);
            } 
            } 

        if (isset($_POST['password'])) {
        $password=$_POST['password']; 
        $password = stripslashes($password);
        $password = htmlspecialchars($password);
        $password = trim($password);
        $password = hash("md5",$password); 
        if ($password =='') {
            unset($password);
            }
            }


if (empty($login) or empty($password)) 
    {
    exit (header('location:index.php'));
    }

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users_data WHERE login='$login'");

    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    if (empty($row['password']))
    {
    exit (header('location:mistake.php'));
    }
    else {

    if ($row['password']==$password) {

    $_SESSION['login']=$row['login']; 
    $_SESSION['users_id']=$row['users_id'];
    header('location:first.php');

    }
    else {

        header('location:mistake.php');



    }
    }
```

The HTML form:

```
<form action="login.php" method="post" class="login">



<label><span>Login:</span>
<input name="login" type="text" size="20" maxlength="100">
</label>




<label><span>Password:</span>
<input name="password" type="password" size="20" maxlength="100">
</label>



<p>
<input type="submit" name="submit" class ="submit" value="Login">
</p>
```

UPD: Thank you for your answers, finally I've got where the problem was - I just specified not enough length of password values in the database.

Comment: what is the password and what do you have stored in the database for the user you are trying?

Comment: echo $row['password'] and echo $password and post here please

Comment: Why does the sql not also use the password?

Comment: Also use `mysqli` instead of `mysql`. Mysql is deprecated.

Comment: You really shouldn't use [MD5 password hashes](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure). Please use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: @AlexAndrei
I dont understand the question. Password is the users password. In the database is stored hashed users password.

Comment: @SugumarVenkatesan It just prints the same hashed password value, both of these.

Comment: @RamRaider Is it necessary? Login and password are stored in the same table.

Comment: if you post it we can try, how to make the if condition return true

Comment: Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: there are way too many conditional statements here that will probably mess up somewhere. I wouldn't waste anymore time with this if I were you, but use something that's already proven to work and ***worthy of this century***. http://stackoverflow.com/a/34158109/

Comment: @SugumarVenkatesan  Now value of it is just "test" and in database it stored hashed as "098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4"

Comment: If you change to  PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security you will not have the problems you're having. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: for test md5 hash value is 098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6 and your stored hash is different "098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4" that's why you are getting to the mistake.php (my opinion)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all why would you store the password in the database without hashing them(e.g. md5).

If you would do that, then there would be no need to process the password and you could just compare the stored `md5(password)`  with the md5 hash of the password posted by the user.

Also w.r.t it is most likely that you are being redirected to the `mistake.php` page instead of the `success.php` page because of the encoding.

It would help if you provide us with the password you are using to test the code (assuming you are testing it. ;) ).

Cheers!

EDIT: Please look at better encryption techniques, as suggested by @jayblancard in the comments below.

Comment: You really shouldn't use [MD5 password hashes](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure).

Comment: Thanks @JayBlanchard, it was an insightful read, but I made the suggestion to use md5 purely for simplicity and better understanding of the "asker".

Comment: While it may be simple it is wrong in this day and age. We should encourage good coding habits and good security management. If we're not going to do that we aren't doing our jobs.

Comment: @Aman concerning the password. Now value of it is just  "test"  and in database it stored hashed as "098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4".

Comment: By passing `test` through md5 [here](http://www.md5.cz/) one gets the hashed value as "098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6" which is 2 characters more than the value you provided.

Comment: @Aman Thats really weird, because I stored it with pretty the same handler of 'password'.

Answer (score 0):

try to use isset() instead of empty

```
if (isset($row['password']))
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 0):

1. I will just advice you to try to debug your code, mistake DOT php is called in multiple places so use a `die("die message")` to see which one is being fired.
2. Since you don't have tests to your code debug output of valid and invalid input and check output.
3. Once you are satisfied with the inputs and outputs, check if conditions if they are behaving as expected like previously using die condition maybe.

NB: your code is messy look at this to lean [basics](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Basic-Login-Authentication-with-PHP-and-MySQL.html)

Also look at [OO programming](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php)