# Login system with mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I would like to get some clear information or reply how to solve the next issue.

Currently i used MySQL connection, but now i want to move onto MySQLi. I dont want to use PDO, so please do not prefer it.

The new mysqli code is this, but its not working also i think i used a bit too much else, which is not needed.

```
<?php
include('includes/functions.php');
session_start();   
if(isset($_POST['login'])) {
if(isset($_POST['username'])) {
    if(isset($_POST['password'])) {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        mysqli_query($query, "SELECT * FROM cm_users WHERE Username = '$username'") or die(mysql_error());
        foreach ($query as $user)
        if(sha3($_POST['password'],256) == $user['Password']) {
            $_SESSION['user'] = $user['Username'];
        if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
            $captcha=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
            }
        if(!$captcha){
            header("Location: login.php");
            echo "<button class='btn btn-block btn-warning btn-sm'>Please check your login details.</button>";
        exit;
        }
        $response=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=******&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
        if($response.success==false)
        {
        echo '<h2>You are spammer ! Get the @$%K out</h2>';
        } else {
        echo '<h2>Thanks for posting comment.</h2>';
        }
            header("Location: redirect.php");
        } else {
            echo "<button class='btn btn-block btn-warning btn-sm'>Please check your login details.</button>";
            include('login.php');
        }
        } else {
            echo "<button class='btn btn-block btn-warning btn-sm'>Please check that you filled out the login form!</button>";
            include('login.php');
        }
}
}
?>
```

Any idea how to fix the issue to get work?

Comment: you're still mixing APIs using `mysql_error()` and we don't know if your connection is in fact `mysqli_`, and that's unknown. Check for the real errors. We also don't know if your POST arrays contain values or not.

Comment: What are you errors? What is $query? Please provide some more code

Comment: then you have a bunch of echos with headers, so you may be outputting before header. error reporting.

Comment: No error just "please check your login details."

Of course i added 

ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL|E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

the $query is $query = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "xxxx", "cmv1");

Comment: Edit: ok, so you have it. Original comment: Your system may not be setup to catch/log/display errors/notices. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything, 
 as well as `or die(mysqli_error($query))` to `mysqli_query()` and change that `mysql_error()` to `mysqli_error($query)` < that is what needs to be changed.

Comment: and this is failing you for sure `foreach ($query as $user)` there is nothing assigned to `$query` (for the query), you're checking a `foreach` against your db connection's variable and that alone should have thrown you an error. edit: had you used the right error function.

Comment: http://cs2d.hu/cm_admin/dologin.php

you can see it live, however error reporting already added its not debug anything currently

Comment: Look [my comment received an upvote...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34358552/login-system-with-mysqli#comment56458824_34358552), there's a reason here ;-) edit: it's up to 2 now.

Comment: i assigned the db connection to it :( its just included by include('includes/functions.php');

Comment: and there you go ;-) assign a variable to the query other than your db connection. solved. `$other_var = mysqli_query($connection, query)...` and use that variable in your `foreach`. would you like my comments as an answer? ;-)

Comment: $test = mysqli_query($query, "SELECT * FROM cm_users WHERE Username = '$username'") or die(mysqli_error($query));
   foreach ($test as $user)

like that?:D

Comment: you missed the `$` --- `$test = mysqli_query....` sure. then `foreach($test..)`.

Comment: yes, edited it now its login, however i still not understand why its takes more than 1 minutes to login :O

Comment: That is not due to your code but probably due to your machine

Comment: that's because of the `foreach` it's going over your entire table of rows/users. that can be cut down to a mere `num_rows()` call and looking if `>0`. No idea why you're using a `foreach` here.

Comment: well, i dont thin, VPS can simple handle it well. Before it was so fast.

Well there is only 2 user in the table, so i dont think it would takes that too much. Maybe SHA3?

Comment: @Fred-ii- he is only going over all the rows where the username is the same as the given username. So he isn't looping through all the users. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: You are right Fredii :)

Comment: @Dacaspex their method is flawed and can be simplified a lot. I wouldn't do a `foreach` for one thing and that alone could be taking a lot resources. A simple check if a row exists, in a while loop with an `if` will suffice, and even then, those are probably not even needed.

Comment: Should i write a tottally new login system then?

Comment: @Marcell I would and using a safer method (you're open to an SQL injection right now). Here, use one of ircmaxell's great answers http://stackoverflow.com/a/29778421/ I suggest it often. Upvote his answer (if you can) and if you use it and worked for you. It's a much simpler method and will work quite fast.

Comment: Thanks people, really appricate all of your replies :)

Comment: You're welcome Marcell.

Comment: @Marcell so, did the comments help solve your question and what would you like to do with it? If it's left unanswered, then it will be in Stack's unanswered category. If you want to post your own answer, Stack does allow you to do that. The choice is yours if you want and if you wish to delete it.

Comment: I did, but cannot accept it for 2 days :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Making this as a wiki* - I have nothing to gain from this, but more for the OP and future visitors to the question.

---

Pulled from comments and slightly modified:

Firstly, you're still mixing APIs using `mysql_error()` where it should read as `mysqli_error($query)` assuming that `$query` is your connection variable used in your connection codes.

Then this is failing you `foreach ($query as $user)` because there is nothing assigned to `$query` (for the query), as you are checking a `foreach` against your db connection's variable and that alone should have thrown you an error, had you used the right error function.

Being `mysqli_error($query)` where that function requires a database connection as a parameter.

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Use [**`mysqli_*` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO**](http://php.net/pdo) with [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).

As suggested, use one of ircmaxell's answers and using a better hashing/query function.

Pulled from his answer:

Just use a library. Seriously. They exist for a reason.

- PHP 5.5+: use [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
- PHP 5.3.7+: use [`password-compat`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) (a compatibility pack for above)
- All others: use [phpass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/)

Don't do it yourself. If you're creating your own salt, **YOU'RE DOING IT WRONG**. You should be using a library that handles that for you.

```
$dbh = new PDO(...);

$username = $_POST["username"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("insert into users set username=?, email=?, password=?");
$stmt->execute([$username, $email, $hash]);
```

And on login:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$result = $stmt->execute([$_POST['username']]);
$users = $result->fetchAll();
if (isset($users[0]) {
    if (password_verify($_POST['password'], $users[0]->password) {
        // valid login
    } else {
        // invalid password
    }
} else {
    // invalid username
}
```