# website username and password is not working

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to have a website with login page but every time I enter the email and password i get "wrong credentials". followings are my codes, first my html code:

```
<form class="form-login" action = "check.php">
                    <div class="errorHandler alert alert-danger no-display">
                        <i class="fa fa-remove-sign"></i> You have some form errors. Please check below.
                    </div>
                    <fieldset>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <span class="input-icon">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user" placeholder="Username">
                                <i class="fa fa-user"></i> </span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group form-actions">
                            <span class="input-icon">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control password" name="pass" placeholder="Password">
                                <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
                                <a class="forgot" href="#">
                                    I forgot my password
                                </a> </span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-actions">
                            <label for="remember" class="checkbox-inline">
                                <input type="checkbox" class="grey remember" id="remember" name="remember">
                                Keep me signed in
                            </label>
                            <button  type="submit" class="btn btn-green pull-right"  name="btn-login"> Login <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></button>
```

then my check.php code:

```
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
// username and password sent from form 
$myusername=$_POST['user']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['pass']; 
echo "$myusername";
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE email='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1){
    // Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file 
    session_register("myusername");
    session_register("mypassword"); 
    header("location:.index2.html");
}
else {
    echo "Wrong credentials!";
}
```

and here is my first row of table:
[admins table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWiNf.png)

and I exactly enter Korivand.neshat@gmail.com as a username and 123456789 as a password in the related fields.

Comment: You never define $tbl_name. You also never check for errors.

Comment: do you have more than one entry with the same credentials?

Comment: i added the table name: $tbl_name="admins"; // Table name  @JohnConde

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: Say no to plain text passwords! Please use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: @JayBlanchard i will secure my code, for now, can you just help me solve this problem?

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.
 Also add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`. You will see quite a few ;-)

Comment: What does `mysql_error`tell you?

Comment: You shouldn't be solving this code as there are just too many issues. You should rewrite using all of information provided and then solve any errors you run into *there*.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I am doing exactly what you are saying if you give me a minute! It is my first time programming php I am learining!

Comment: and you really should be using functions of "this century". If this is intended to be a live site, I strongly suggest you stop what you're doing and start using `mysqli_` or PDO with a prepared statement as well as a safe password hashing function such as `password_hash()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> and I exactly enter Korivand.neshat@gmail.com as a username

Since the record in the table is `"korivand.neshat@gmail.com"`, if your database is using case-sensitive comparisons then you've entered an incorrect username.

It's also possible that there exists more than 1 record with that username?  In which case your comparison would fail:

```
if($count==1)
```

Also, a couple of ***very important*** notes:

1. Your code is **wide open** to **SQL injection**.  Use prepared statements and query parameters instead of *executing user input as code*.  Start by [reading this](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).
2. You are storing user passwords as **plain text**.  This is *grossly irresponsible* to your users.  Passwords should be obscured by a 1-way hash and should *never* be retrievable by *anybody*.  Not even by you as the system owner.

---

**Edit:** As pointed out by @Fred in a comment below.  Your form is using the GET method:

```
<form class="form-login" action = "check.php">
```

But you're checking for POST values:

```
$myusername=$_POST['user'];
```

Either change one or the other.

Comment: i entered everything in lower case and changed the if statement to if($count)  but still the same result. about your notes, I will secure it.thnks

Comment: `<form class="form-login" action = "check.php">` and POST arrays. You know what form defaults to when a method isn't specified ;-)

Comment: @user3696174: Do you define any of the other variables you're using?  Such as `$tbl_name`?  What is the actual query being executed when this runs?

Comment: and OP is using the deprecated `session_register()` function. Could be a lot of things at play and the OP really needs to check for errors ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- i didn't catch what you said, can you explain more?

Comment: @user3696174 [Read my comment to you earlier...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34745373/website-username-and-password-is-not-working#comment57237057_34745373)

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: user in /home/hevak/public_html/cp/check.php on line 14

Notice: Undefined index: pass in /home/hevak/public_html/cp/check.php on line 15
Wrong credentials!

Comment: @Fred-ii-  it is what i am getting, please check above comment

Comment: @user3696174 Look `<form class="form-login" action = "check.php">` and you have `$_POST` that's why and exactly as David outlined in his answer. I'm leaning more towards using POST because it's safer than GET, so just do `<form method="post" class="form-login" action = "check.php">` and that error should go away. But as I stated above under your question in another comment, you shouldn't be using that code and you will spend more time trying to fix it, rather than finding yourself something more secure, such as this answer by ircmaxell http://stackoverflow.com/a/29778421/1415724