# Why is my row_count condition always returning 0?

Tags: php

I have this part of code where I have my `$row_count` is always returning a value of 0 even i have the right username and password.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE uName = ? AND uPassword = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('ss',$username,$password);
$stmt->execute() or die ($stmt->error);
$get_result=$stmt->get_result();
print_r($get_result); //DEBUG purpose
$row_count= $stmt->num_rows;
print_r($row_count); die;// DEBUG purpose
$stmt->close();
$conn->close();

if ($row_count>0){
    $_SESSION['uName'] = $username;


    echo "Logged in";
    exit();
}else{
    echo "Wrong credentials";
    exit();
}

}
```

btw, i have more rows on my tables does that affect the whole process? My code is always going to the else statment.
`mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 10 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 0 [type] => 0 )` this is how i determined its always returning as 0. Thanks for your help no need of hashing the passwords just need to return a value of `>1` thanks. :D

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form action = "" method = "post">
    <input type = "text" name="username"><br>
    <input type = "password" name = "password"><br>
    <input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "Login">
    <a href = "register.php">Create Account</a>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the form.

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat). Make sure you ***[don't escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: I just want to create a very simple login without hashing passwords. Is that even possible? @JayBlanchard

Comment: Sure, it is possible, just not recommended. Who would want to use a site where the passwords are easily accessible?

Comment: Instead of `print_r($row_count);` you should have `echo $row_count;`. `$stmt->num_rows` returns an integer, not an array.

Comment: Oh, this is okay for me. It's just a simple plain code for my thesis project. Can you help me with my problem? @JayBlanchard

Comment: At the beginning of your script do `print_r($_POST);`. My guess is that your variables are not set. Can you also post the form code?

Comment: BTW...I hate when people say *"I'm not that far along..."* or *"This site will not be public..."* or *"It's only for school, so security doesn't matter..."*. If teachers and professors are not talking about security from day one, they're doing it wrong. Challenge them. They're teaching sloppy and dangerous coding practices which students will have to unlearn later. I also hate it when folks say, *"I'll add security later..."* or *"Security isn't important now..."*. If you don't have time to do it right the first time, when will you find the time to add it later?

Comment: I've edited my post and there's my form. @JayBlanchard

Comment: This exact same code was posted a day or so ago, I remember it quite well. However, that other account/question were most likely deleted and have left no traces whatsoever. What it didn't do though, is wipe it from "my memory" and I remember code quite well. So in short, check for errors; you're not doing that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [check if row exists with mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22252904/check-if-row-exists-with-mysql)

Comment: Yeah, but instead of scolding me of my incompetence can you please help me with this? :c @Fred-ii-

Comment: Can you show us the result of `print_r($_POST);`?

Comment: Here, use this http://stackoverflow.com/a/29778421/ and make sure the password column is 60+

Comment: `Array ( [username] => Batz [password] => 123 [submit] => Login ) `  That is what i've just typed on the fields. and on my database its the correct username and password @JayBlanchard

Comment: May you go to a chat room, please?