# User Authentication Password Hashes

Tags: php, mysqli, hash

Okay so i'm trying to make a basic user authentication system. Well I already made it. But what im trying to do now is check the users password against a hash. I'm using $hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); but for the login page I want to check the users password with the hashed password in the database so they can login. How can I do this?

Register.php:

```
    <?php
include('config.php'); 

if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

function mres($input){
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()){
        $input = stripslashes($input);
    }
    return mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['$input']);
}

$email=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
$username=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['username']);
$password=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['password']);
$hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$query = $conn->query("select * from users where username='$username'");
$rows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
if ($rows == 1) {
echo "User already exist redirecting in 5 seconds!";
} else {
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, email)
VALUES ('$username', '$hash', '$email')";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
}

$conn->close();
header("Location: ../index.php");
?>
```

Login.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
include('config.php'); 

$error=''; 

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
if (empty($_POST['userid']) || empty($_POST['passid'])) {
$error = "Username or Password is invalid";
}
else
{


$user=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['userid']);
$pass=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['passid']);
$hash = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$passv = password_verify($pass, $hash);
$query = $conn->query("select * from users where password='$passv' AND username='$user'");
$rows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
if ($rows == 1) {
$_SESSION['login_user']=$username;
$_SESSION['username']=$user;
$_SESSION['checklogin']== true;
header("location: ../profile.php"); 
} else {
$error = "Username or Password is invalid";
}
mysqli_close($conn);
}
}   
?>
```

(Yes i know i added that function there that im not using in register. Its for future use im saving it for now. I have plans for it.)

Comment: Read this documentation http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

Comment: I am but it keeps giving me invalid password.

Comment: Im pretty sure its generating a new hash for the password verify when it shouldnt. I just need it to check that password for that hash or whatever it needs to do to login.

Comment: I got it to work but it has to be in the same file as it was hashed. Now when i store the hash in a table and want to check it in another file against the users input it wont work.

Comment: Then your data is getting malformed between storage and re-use, and without code samples, no one here can help you any further.

Comment: Okay ill edit with code samples.

Comment: Do check that the hash that `password_hash()` produces is exactly the same as when you then read it out of the database. Eg you may be prone to data truncation if your column storage length isn't sufficient.

Comment: Your databasing in `login.php` is confused, you should be loading the hash out of the database by username and then running `password_verify()` on the hash that's in the database with the users post data password. You should note that `password_hash()` gives different outputs each time.

Comment: Thanks ill try that.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26536293/php-password-hash-password-verify

Answer (score 0):

Select the password from database using the username. Get the hash password from the database and use password_verify(inputPassword,hashPassword) with an if statement.