# If not exists, insert into

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a social network and if a username or email is the same I don't want to enter the details into the MySQL database.

Here's the PHP I'm using:

```
if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){

  $datejoined = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time());;
  $verified = 0;
  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];

  $query = "INSERT INTO `members` (username, password, email, verified, datejoined) 
       VALUES ('$username', md5('$password'), '$email', '0', '$datejoined')";
```

Some help would really be appreciated!

Comment: You need to use `if-else` , where ever required.

Comment: Add a unique constraint to those fields in your database?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8449540/php-detect-mysql-update-insertion-failure-due-to-violated-unique-constraint

Comment: first use select to see if username or email exist or not , then use if-else statement to insert into database

Comment: Your code is open to [SQL injection](http://www.bobby-tables.com/). Additionally MD5 is [not secure for protecting passwords](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure). Switch to [password_hash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26536293/php-password-hash-password-verify) instead

Comment: `md5($password)`? Really? Just left it plaintext - no difference for today.

Answer (score 0):

Create unique indexes to spot duplicates.

```
create unique index unq_members on members(username);
create unique index unq_members on members(email);
```

Then, ignore the duplicates when doing an insert:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `members`(username, password, email, verified, datejoined)
    VALUES ('$username', md5('$password'), '$email', '0', '$datejoined');
```

Or use:

```
INSERT INTO `members`(username, password, email, verified, datejoined)
    VALUES ('$username', md5('$password'), '$email', '0', '$datejoined')
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE username = username;
```

Comment: **Note:** the `IGNORE` part ignores more things than just the duplicate insertion. [MORE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/548541/insert-ignore-vs-insert-on-duplicate-key-update) and [MORE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html)